# Как заставить ботов Яндекса парсить spa на React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, seo

Есть сайт написанный на React.js, весь рендеринг происходит на клиенте.

Серверная часть написана на Koa.js.

Как я понял, яндекс не индексирует spa приложения, судя из статей в интернете наиболее простой способ - это настроить перерендер страниц.

Но я так до конца четко не смог осознать принцип работы перерендера и как его вообще нужно настраивать.

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то рендерить нужно на сервере. SSR (server side rendering).

Comment: либо используете сервер рендер, либо библиотеки типа prerender. Если prerender ставить как отдельный сервер, то на вашем сервере нужно будет отделять ботов от людей, и всем ботам отдавать результат работы сервера prerender. -
http://prerender.test/render?url=https://www.example.com/ - такой запрос к серверу пререндера вернёт вам полный html для https://www.example.com/

Comment: @xFloooo, а отрендеренные страницы по какому то адресу лежат? Если рендерить на серверах prerender.io

Comment: @Dmitry Filippov по \GET запросу они возвращаются и вроде даже как кэшируются, но если хотите, то можете сами сохранить в файлики...